# Sending post to page from iOS with publish_stream permission

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, fbconnect

I am currently connecting my iOS native app to a facebook page in order to post a message to that wall. I can access the wall but for some reason there's no message text set. I asked the user for 'publish_stream' permissions.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *message = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"some text", @"message", @"http://path/to/itunes/", @"link", nil];

NSString *changeJSON = [message JSONRepresentation];

NSLog(@"changeJSON: %@", changeJSON);

NSData *myPostData = [changeJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *myURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/pageId/feed?access_token=%@", facebook.accessToken];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [myPostData length] ] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: myPostData];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"return string: %@", returnString);

[facebook logout:self];
```

The string which is encoded to a NSData object is the following:

```
{"message":"some text","link":"http://path/to/itunes/"}
```

Thanks and have a nice day :-)

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to post JSON to the GraphAPI? If so, you can't post JSON to Facebook, but instead have to use parameters when posting (either query string or HTTP request parameters).

All posting actions are done via HTTP POST with parameters and all responses are done in JSON. You can read more on this via the [Graph API reference under publishing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api).

See: [POST Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).

Comment: Thanks man, that's the solution. My mistake now it's working like a charm :-)